# How to get current depth and maximum depth/size of Solace Queue in Java? Which API can be used to get these details?

Tags: solace

Need API details to get number of Readers and writers to queue as well as current size and maximum size of the solace queue

Answer (score 1):

You can use SEMP (Solace Element Management Protocol) to view details about a queue such as current depth and maximum spool quota on Solace PubSub+.

If you are using a Java data client, you can enable SEMP over the message bus to send a SEMP request through the data channel.

Full details are available here:
https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-VPNs.htm#SEMP-MBus

There is also a sample bundled with the JCSMP API called SempGetOverMB.java that demonstrates the use of this features.